# Only APPLY the CSS to within an element

Tags: css

```
nav ul {
}

nav ul li {
    margin-left: 7px;
}

nav.ul li a, a:link, a:visited {
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
}
```

I only want the code above to style the elements within the `<nav></nav>`

Now however it does as well style the `<a href="">` outside the nav element. How can I make sure it does what I want?

Comment: This: `nav.ul li a, a:link, a:visited` doesn't inherit. Should be: `nav.ul li a, nav.ul li a:link, nav.ul li a:visited`.

Comment: Ok, instead of adding this to all the answers I'll just put it here:

There's a period (.) between nav and ul (it's nav.ul instead of nav ul) so that should be removed too, otherwise it's looking for a <nav class="ul"> when the earlier code sample has those as separate elements.

Comment: @nbsp - You are correct, the ` ` (space) selector is correct, the `.` (or subclass) is wrong and being perpetrated in most of the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules as you have them, will only apply within a `nav` element, except this:

```
nav.ul li a, a:link, a:visited {
```

This rule applies to `a:link` and `a:visited`.  You want this:

```
nav.ul li a, nav.ul li a:link, nav.ul li a:visited {
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because this line is incorrect:

```
nav.ul li a, a:link, a:visited {
```

It should be:

```
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
```

After the comma (,) the CSS is applying to all `a` tags as there's not preceding selectors specified. Also you've got a period (.) in the `nav ul` in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Change your rule:

```
nav.ul li a, a:link, a:visited
```

to:

```
nav.ul li a, nav.ul li a:link, nav.ul li a:visited
```

By omitting the nav.ul li part between the comma separation, you're effectively applying to to links outside of the nav.ul li.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is targeting a:link and a:visited without using descendent selectors. Using the following should fix your problem:

```
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: There's a period (.) between nav and ul (it's nav.ul instead of nav ul) so that should be removed too, otherwise it's looking for a <nav class="ul"> when the earlier code sample has those as separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your selectors are preceded with `nav ul li`.

```
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```